# CSS Grid With Resizer Wonkiness (no js)

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

Seriously pulling out what hair I have left on this one...

TLDR : :

CSS only resizer works great with multiple Grid columns except when there is little (narrow?) content in the most right column?

Yeah...

*read on...*

GOAL: To resize the middle "results" column using **CSS** only.

*All three examples are identical EXCEPT for the text in the `<p>`s in the middle right panels.*

---

EXAMPLE 01:

Paragraphs in both right panels.

Resizer works as expected...

[CodePen example 01](https://codepen.io/dragontheory/pen/abYVwdb?editors=1100)

[image: CodePen example 01]

---

EXAMPLE 02:

Removed all but one word in the `<p>` in middle right panel.

Resizer works as expected...

[CodePen example 02](https://codepen.io/dragontheory/pen/qBoVjxa?editors=1100)

[image: CodePen example 02]

---

EXAMPLE 03:

Removed all but one word in the `<p>`s in BOTH right panels.

***RESIZER IS STUPID!***

*Middle panel suddenly starts resizing on both sides as if center justified!*

[CodePen example 03](https://codepen.io/dragontheory/pen/MWVOoQM?editors=1100)

[image: CodePen example 03]

*WHY!?!?!*

*WHAT STRANGE OBSCURE CSS PROPERTY AM I MISSING!?!?!?!?*

*SAVE THE LAST HAIR ON MY HEAD!!!* *PLEASE!!!*

Relevant CSS:

```
*:before, *:after, *, ::after, ::before {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* GRID ONLY FOR LAYOUT */

/* PANEL WRAPPER */
app-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* ALL PANELS */
app-panel {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  align-content: start;
}

/* HEADER/FOOTER */
app-panel:first-of-type,
app-panel:last-of-type {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 1rem;
}

app-class {justify-self: center;}
app-user, app-version {justify-self: end;}

/* NAV */
app-panel:nth-of-type(2) {width: max-content;}

app-panel:nth-of-type(3) {
  resize: horizontal; /* the STUPID resizer */
  min-width: 20rem;
  max-width: 60vw; /* keeps resizer from going beyond edge of screen */
}

/* Just to show nothing special about <p>s... */
p, h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<!-- Minimal structural markup -->

<app-container>
  <!-- header -->
  <app-panel></app-panel>
  <!-- nav -->
  <app-panel>
    <panel-list>
      <list-item></list-item>
      <list-item></list-item>
      <list-item></list-item>
    </panel-list>
  </app-panel>
  <!-- results -->
  <app-panel>
    <panel-list>
      <list-item></list-item>
      <list-item></list-item>
      <list-item></list-item>
    </panel-list>
  </app-panel>
  <!-- details -->
  <app-panel>
    <p></p>
  </app-panel>
  <!-- meta -->
  <app-panel>
    <p></p>
  </app-panel>
  <!-- footer -->
  <app-panel></app-panel>
</app-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your columns size individually.

line 61 `grid-template-columns: max-content min-content auto auto;`

fork of codepen3 : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LYdOjvg